# Base address of exe?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
    tibiaWindow = FindWindow( L"TibiaClient", NULL);

    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( tibiaWindow, &PID );

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID); //Open Process for Read/Write
    short mana = 0;
    void* ptr = (void*)hProcess+0x3C2D00;
    if( !ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ptr, &mana, 2, 0) ){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        statusBar()->showMessage( QString::number(mana), 3000 );
    }

    return true;
```

This is supposed to read the mana from a game which is located at tibia.exe + 0x3CD2D00. But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? How do I get the base address of that window?

Comment: Define "doesn't work", in the case you are getting unseen errors you need to check return codes.

Comment: Is the PID valid? Is the process handle valid? Is your offset valid? Does the game have an anticheat? Not working isn't very informative.

Comment: `hProcess` is a process **`HANDLE`**. Interpreting as a pointer to the base address of a process is fairly creative. And certainly not what you want.

Comment: Do you want the address of the window or the address of the program controlling the window?

Comment: @Thomas *"The address of the window"* certainly doesn't make sense. Windows do not have an address.

Answer (score 5):

To get the base address of a module in another process requires two steps:

1. Retrieve all module handles loaded into the process using [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx).
2. Iterate over the list of module handles and query for the module name using either [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx) or [`GetModuleBaseName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196.aspx) until you find a match.

The module handle you get from step 2. is the base address of the module in the queried process' address space.

The offset you posted (`0x3CD2D00`) may not be part of the actual image `tibia.exe`. This would imply that the module is at least 63MB in size, which doesn't sound right. It may reside in some other module's static data, or possibly in heap memory, rendering your proposed approach useless.