# Can't get real address of C++ program

Tags: c++, winapi

With the help of the script that will be below, I get the "base address" of the program where it wants to become, but in fact it gets further, apparently due to the fact that the RAM is busy.

How can I get a real address?

Example:

modulBase = 0x400000
Actual address: 0x17E0A8

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAdress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName) {

    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);

        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {

            do {

                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {

                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }

            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));

        }

    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Which processor are you using?  For example, the ARM processor uses a *flat* address space, not segmented.

Answer (score 0):

`MODULEENTRY32::modBaseAddr` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-moduleentry32) as:

> `modBaseAddr`
>
> The base address of the module **in the context of the owning process**.

That means it is a *relative* value. To get the *absolute* address, you need the load address of the owning process, then you can add `modBaseAddr` to it. To get the load address of the process, get the `modBaseAddr` of the `.exe` module that created the process.

Alternatively, to get the address of a particular module in a process, use `EnumProcessModules()` and `GetModuleFileNameEx()`/`GetModuleBaseName()` instead, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20166509/65863) to [Base address of exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166200/)